# reload page redirects to login page in angular 6 after deploy in IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, rest

My Project is done with Angular 6 and Web Api2.It worked perfectly in local server.But after deploy it in IIS,when i try to reload a page or open a url in new tab,it redirects to login page.plz save me....

Comment: Further debugging the issue might be of help. This can be due to multiple problems, but you would need to further debug. E.g. First identify if the problem is server or client. If there are no console errors, or angular files are being loaded correctly, or if the base url for your application is correct (this last part is important if you are deploying to a virtual path). Server errors can be diagnosed by checking network calls and server logging. You will have to explain this error further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may not be saving the session token.

To do this, you could use *localStorage* or *sessionStorage*. The cache will not be refreshed on app reload (https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/).

> localStorage and sessionStorage accomplish the exact same thing and have the same API, but with sessionStorage the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed, while with localStorage the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.

Maybe this will help you debug:

- What are you doing in local server? Are you calling a real service? Maybe you are mocking that and that is why it is working.
- Login with correct credentials in remote deployed app.
- Check that your app is making the right http request to your login service.
- Check that in the response a session token is returned.
- Check that this token is saved somewhere (sessionStorage/localStorage).